# Adjust table record in center

Tags: tables

i have this latex table

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}}
    \hline
    Metric& cca vs. cca1 &cca vs. King James Bible\\[0.1cm]
    \hline
    Average codelength  & 0.84  & 1.84 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 unigram & 7.65  & 10.52 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 unigram & 6.94  & 10.05 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 unigram & 6.38  & 9.72 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 unigram & 4.88  & 7.54 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 bigram & 8.52  & 11.25 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 bigram & 6.68  & 10.23 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 bigram & 5.94  & 9.38 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 bigram & 4.17  & 7.19 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 trigram & 5.4   & 9.56 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 trigram & 4.77  & 8.68 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 trigram & 4.6   & 8.17 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 trigram & 3.58  & 6.3 \\[0.1cm]
    \% of words in 1st corpus not in 2nd corpus &6.05  & 8.73 \\[0.1cm]
    \% of words in 2nd corpus not in 1st  corpus & 5.54  & 2.94 \\[0.1cm]
    Top 10 unseen words in 1st corpus & Mr. Mrs. Dr. Mr SIC J. St. Colour Fig. R. & LORD Shalt and was are hast Is Were be \\[0.1cm]
    Top 10 unseen words in 2nd  corpus & Mr\& **f Mrs\& **h Program Dr\& <The **f. Center St\& & Has Mr\& American Mrs\& Around during United Does don't didn't \\[0.1cm]
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

how i can center the record of this table to have better table shape

especially i have some record with multi line text as bellow ?

[image: table]

Answer (score 2):

You could set the "main" column type of columns 2 and 3 to `S` (provided by the `siunitx` package) to center and decimal-align the numeric entries, while also using a suitably adjusted `p{<width>}` column type for selected other cells within those columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}
\usepackage{siunitx} % center and decimal-align numeric entries
\sisetup{table-format=1.2} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table with three columns}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\smallskip % some separation between caption and tabular env.
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.1cm} % so you don't have to add [0.1cm] after every "\\"
\centering
%  \footnotesize %% not needed, is it?
\begin{tabular}{PSS}
    \hline
    Metric& \multicolumn{1}{c}{cca vs. cca1} &
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{cca vs. King James Bible}\\
    \hline
    Average codelength  & 0.84  & 1.84 \\
    Top1 unigram & 7.65  & 10.52 \\
    Top5 unigram & 6.94  & 10.05 \\
    Top10 unigram & 6.38  & 9.72 \\
    Top100 unigram & 4.88  & 7.54 \\
    Top1 bigram & 8.52  & 11.25 \\
    Top5 bigram & 6.68  & 10.23 \\
    Top10 bigram & 5.94  & 9.38 \\
    Top100 bigram & 4.17  & 7.19 \\
    Top1 trigram & 5.4   & 9.56 \\
    Top5 trigram & 4.77  & 8.68 \\
    Top10 trigram & 4.6   & 8.17 \\
    Top100 trigram & 3.58  & 6.3 \\
    \% of words in 1st corpus not in 2nd corpus &6.05  & 8.73 \\
    \% of words in 2nd corpus not in 1st  corpus & 5.54  & 2.94 \\
    Top 10 unseen words in 1st corpus & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Mr. Mrs. Dr. Mr SIC J. St. Colour Fig. R.} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{LORD Shalt and was are hast Is Were be} \\
    Top 10 unseen words in 2nd corpus & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Mr\& **f Mrs\& **h Program Dr\& <The **f. Center St\&} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Has Mr\& American Mrs\& Around during United Does don't didn't}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of the `array` package.

You can add extra commands to act on a table column. So to centre a p colum you can write

`>{\centering}p{3cm}`

or in full

`\begin{tabular}{>{centering}p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}}`

In that case the centering wouldonly act on the first column and you have to add it for each column you rquire it.
This is a bit annoying to write so just define your own new column type

`\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}`

then you can write `P{3cm}` and you get a text-centred column of the defined width. Sometimes text can break funny over narrow table columns. then you may want to consider the `ragged2e` package to replace \centering with \Centering which does a better job.