# Improve appearance of table

Tags: tables

i have this table

```
{\scriptsize

    \begin{longtable}{p{3.5cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
    \caption{word frequrnt} \label{tab:addlabeloooo} \\
     \\ [0.1cm]
     \hline
    Metric& Brown vs. LOB   &Brown vs. King James Bible\\[0.1cm]
    \hline 
    Average codelength  & 0.84  & 1.84 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 unigram & 7.65  & 10.52 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 unigram & 6.94  & 10.05 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 unigram & 6.38  & 9.72 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 unigram & 4.88  & 7.54 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 bigram & 8.52  & 11.25 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 bigram & 6.68  & 10.23 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 bigram & 5.94  & 9.38 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 bigram & 4.17  & 7.19 \\[0.1cm]
    Top1 trigram & 5.4   & 9.56 \\[0.1cm]
    Top5 trigram & 4.77  & 8.68 \\[0.1cm]
    Top10 trigram & 4.6   & 8.17 \\[0.1cm]
    Top100 trigram & 3.58  & 6.3 \\[0.1cm]
    \% of words in 1st corpus not in 2nd corpus &6.05  & 8.73 \\[0.1cm]
    \% of words in 2nd corpus not in 1st  corpus & 5.54  & 2.94 \\[0.1cm]
    Top 10 unseen words in 1st corpus & Mr. Mrs. Dr. Mr SIC J. St. Colour Fig. R. & LORD Shalt and was are hast Is Were be \\[0.1cm]
    Top 10 unseen words in 2nd  corpus & Mr\& **f Mrs\& **h Program Dr\& <The **f. Center St\& & Has Mr\& American Mrs\& Around during United Does don't didn't \\[0.1cm] \hline
    \end{longtable}
    }
```

But it looks ugly, as there are some long lines as in picture[image: this]

Does anybody have an idea how to improve its appearance?

Comment: What do you mean by "long lines"?

Comment: @Chris raw with more than one line

Comment: Is there a meaningful difference between this new question and [Adjust table record in center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149899/5001)?

Comment: This happens because you limit the length of the table rows. When the text then gets too long, it will cause a line break. You can either shorten your text to avoid this or not use the `p-argument` in the table definition. Then the text will be written in one line but this may cause a table which is bigger than your paper format.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it is. The previous question was on how to adjust table record (technical). This question is on typography; how to make the result prettier than the output from the technical solution. A conceptual total different questions. An answer may be: Make two different tables.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not put such different value types into the same column. I’d split it into three tables at least. Anyhow, some minor improvements …

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,siunitx}
\newcommand*{\gram}[1]{{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}%
               *2{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]}}
\toprule
Metric & {Brown vs. LOB} & {Brown vs. KJB} \\
\midrule
Average codelength & 0.84  &  1.84 \\
\midrule
Top1   unigram & 7.65  & 10.52 \\
Top5   unigram & 6.94  & 10.05 \\
Top10  unigram & 6.38  &  9.72 \\
Top100 unigram & 4.88  &  7.54 \\
Top1    bigram & 8.52  & 11.25 \\
Top5    bigram & 6.68  & 10.23 \\
Top10   bigram & 5.94  &  9.38 \\
Top100  bigram & 4.17  &  7.19 \\
Top1   trigram & 5.40  &  9.56 \\
Top5   trigram & 4.77  &  8.68 \\
Top10  trigram & 4.60  &  8.17 \\
Top100 trigram & 3.58  &  6.30 \\
\midrule
Words in 1st, not in 2nd corpus & 6.05\,\%  & 8.73\,\% \\
Words in 2nd, not in 1st corpus & 5.54\,\%  & 2.94\,\% \\
\midrule
Top 10 unseen words in 1st corpus 
& \multicolumn1{p{0.33\textwidth}}{\gram{Mr.} 
  \gram{Mrs.} \gram{Dr.} \gram{Mr} \gram{SIC} 
  \gram{J.} \gram{St.} \gram{Colour} \gram{Fig.} \gram{R.}} 
& \multicolumn1{p{0.33\textwidth}}{\gram{LORD} 
  \gram{Shalt} \gram{and} \gram{was} \gram{are} 
  \gram{hast} \gram{Is} \gram{Were} \gram{be}} \\
Top 10 unseen words in 2nd corpus
& \multicolumn1{p{0.33\textwidth}}{\gram{Mr\&} 
  \gram{**f} \gram{Mrs\&} \gram{**h} \gram{Program} 
  \gram{Dr\&} \gram{<The} \gram{**f.} \gram{Center} \gram{St\&}}
& \multicolumn1{p{0.33\textwidth}}{\gram{Has} 
  \gram{Mr\&} \gram{American} \gram{Mrs\&} 
  \gram{Around} \gram{during} \gram{United} 
  \gram{Does} \gram{don't} \gram{didn't}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison} \label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```